# Regarding Baker-Node interaction

Tags: baking, node, baker, codebase

Does baker implementation currently include a way to tell node what block it wants to bake on?

Edit:
I want to know if what does baker do after it finds out it has a baking slot?
What I know is that It asks node to send the a block which node has been preparing since last block it received, signs it and ask node to inject it.
I am curious whether baker can ask node to extend any head of their choosing, or it is completely upto node to decide which head to extend using this new block.

Comment: Edited with more details. Let me know if questions makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

There's only ever 1 head. The node knows the current head. The baker binary reads the current head from the database files and bakes head+1 when it is your turn. The node does not "prepare" any blocks. The node simply relays operations and validates signatures. Endorsers inject endorsement operations; bakers scrape endorsements from the mempool and construct a new block/head and submit it at the appropriate time.